# ContextMenuStrip stops working on blank area in ObjectListView

Tags: c#, contextmenu, objectlistview

In my .NET 4.0 WinForms app I have ObjectListView 2.5.1.18477 and a ContextMenuStrip associated with it.

The context menu displays fine when I right click on a data row in the ObjectListView, but if I right click on a blank area, such as the red cross, then the context menu never shows again on the ObjectListView no matter where I click.

How can I get the context menu to keep displaying no matter where I click in the ObjectListView?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah. Some other code was catching the mouse event and failing.